# How to properly set DNS for subdomains on Plesk 12?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I re-installed a virtual server of mine and updated it to Plesk 12.0.18 (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS). 
The reset and reinstall was done automatically by [HostEurope](https://www.hosteurope.de/en/), the update from Plesk 11 to 12 was done through Plesks "Updates and Upgrades".

I [edited the Nameserver in Plesks DNS Template](http://faq.hosteurope.de/?cpid=11430#english), and then added my main domain, which works as expected.

Then I added a `mail.domain.com` subdomain and installed my webmail, and everything works as expected.

After that, I added a `marketing.domain.com` subdomain. The DNS record got added automatically:

`marketing.domain.com     A    IP`
(IP = real servers ip)

But that doesn't work. `ping` (from pc) and also `nslookup` (from shell) are negative.

I thought that Plesk would add the right DNS automatically when creating a new subdomain, but it looks like something is missing. Do I manually need to set a specific DNS record for every subdomain, or do I have a mistake in my DNS-Template?

[image: Plesk DNS Template]

I'm pretty new to DNS/Plesk so it might be obvious, but I'm really not seeing it, thanks for the help.

Solved it with the help of dartonw.

---

**Solution:**

When hosting on HostEurope you have to set your DNS settings outside Plesk in your Customer Panel: [Domainservices -> Edit AutoDNS](http://faq.hosteurope.de/index.php?cpid=12785)

Thanks to *dartonw* and *Jamin Andrews*.

Comment: I don't see a record for marketing in your screenshot. It looks like mail/webmail records are part of the hosting company's default DNS template; rather than being added automatically when you set up the host they may have already been there. You'll probably need to manually add the A record for marketing.

Comment: That is just the DNS-Template, if I go the the parents domain DNS there is a record: `marketing.domain.com    A    IP` (IP = real servers ip)

Comment: You may be getting a cached negative response. If you query the NS directly, e.g. `server ns2.hans.hosteurope.de` from within nslookup, then type in marketing.domain.com, does it resolve?

Comment: Just checked with the NS and got: `server can't find marketing.domain.com: NXDOMAIN`. I also checked `mail.domain.com` with the NS to be sure, and got a correct response.

Comment: Sounds like your new record has not propagated to the actual NS. Have you contacted HostEurope? They may have more insight on the matter.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. Looks like I needed to set the DNS outside of Plesk in some "hidden" menu-point.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue on the surface looks like you need to manually add DNS records into hosteurope main DNS. Plesk is a stand alone server admin and unless you slave your DNS (which is unlikely via Hosteurope) you need to add to your hosts DNS.

This is the most common issue with hosted VPS/Containers running Plesk/cPanel, they are normally not slaved to hosting providers DNS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you (or someone) clarify this answer?  How do you "slave your DNS to the hosting providers DNS"?  Can you actually do this from Plesk?

Comment: Please don't copy paste answers from different websites. At least give attribution

Comment: @ZaidKhan:  Did you check the date stamp, for the answer, which appears on this other website?  I have only come across one duplicate, where it seems it was this answer that was duplicated.  Not the other way around.